# passing run time configuration from springboot to Vue app

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

I have an VueJS Application wrapped up in Springboot application building using Gradle.

I do have env files inside my vue app which contains environemnt specific configuration.

I Use Gradle to do npm build and pass teh mode there to choose env file however i want to build once run everywehere.

I want to pass configuration to VUe app from my application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing profile based configuration in spring-boot.
This way you can use environment variables to specify which configuration set to be used.

[Here is the example of implementing profile based configuration](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-profiles-1)

Comment: Well thanks for response however I am aware of using spring profiles in Springboot, however I want to pass those env to vue code wrapped inside